# Gmail app on App store only has "Open" and not "Install" option

Tags: iphone, mail.app, gmail

I have an iPhone X and I configured the pre-installed Mail app to my Gmail account. After using it for some time I recently got an email from Google saying "you are missing out, update to the Gmail app". So I clicked on the "Get the app" button which took me to the App Store and there was an "Open" button which, of course, opens the Gmail app.

The problem is that apparently the app does not get installed, so if I fully close it, then the only way to access it again is to go the the App Store, look for the app and click on the "Open" button which is, frankly, super annoying.

Of course there is a work around which is to keep the app always open and then swipe through all the open apps until I get to the Gmail one, but that is also cumbersome and annoying.

Is there a way to actually have the app installed and available in the phone's home screen?

Comment: Have you tried a restart of your iPhone X ?? - and if you in Screen Time have “Disabling Apps” set to “Don’t allow”, try set it to “Allow”

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app and reinstalling it?